# C++ operator inheritance and overloading

Tags: c++

I have a base class A and a derived class B. A and B both define the [] operator but not with the same argument type. Still, when I try to use the [] operator on an object of type B with A arg C++ doesn't find A's def of this. Very annoying. What's the rule?

Comment: Can you show use the code you are using in an [mcve]?

Comment: You mean that you want to call A's operator[] ?

Comment: @NathanOliver That's the problem: To present a cleancut version of bare essentials for you to inspect. If you don't know of any rule prohibiting what I tried to do I may have to do this.

Comment: @thefunkyjunky Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 4):

The operator in class B hides the operator in class A. This is a problem with any method defined in a derived class that overloads a method in a super class. If name lookup finds a name match in `B` it doesn't look in `A`, even if the match(s) found in `B` can't be called.

You need to bring it into the scope of B:

```
class X{};
class Y{};

class A {
public:
    auto operator[](X) {};
};

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::operator[]; // <-- you need this
    auto operator[](Y){};
};


int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    b[X{}]; // OK
    b[Y{}]; // OK
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. I can't understand why C++ behaves like this, though. If it doesn't find an operand match in class B it should look in A. Of course! That's the whole point of inheritance.

Comment: @Henrik - no, that would lead to mysterious bugs. Imagine that you've written a class derived from a library class, and your class has a member function `void foo(double);`.  You can call it with an argument of type `int`, and the argument will be converted to `double` in order to make the call. Now suppose a maintenance release of the library adds a member function to that base class, `void foo(int);`. Now your code would quietly call the base class version instead of your version.

Comment: @Pete, I beg to differ. If a third party offers a library class it should publish the interface with documentation and it must remain fixed. Whatever changes are made should only affect the hidden code, never the user interface or the functionality. Backward compatibility is paramount. That's why industry standards change so slowly.